# First Person Controller problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

i m new use of unity3d softwere. i am facing a problem with First Person Controller. how to control this.. please reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Unify Wiki under Scripts >> Character Controller Scripts. There are several scripts for advanced Controllers like the RigidbodyFPSWalker:

http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=RigidbodyFPSWalker

andDo reply how u like my ans ..!!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the docs and do what it says. It will work perfectly.